# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException is thrown while sending email in java

Tags: java

I am beginner in java and I want to send an email in java, for that I am using this code in Java. But my code is throwing an exception, and I need a heads-up why…

This is stack trace of exception:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsNX
534-5.7.14 No6jJbDc4l7fZ_WLdBD0sNHIIp_nLvplRMm0bYFBnZBF_XOyVvNSdd1FenDZJPwBTFQyRH
534-5.7.14 lriPK3myMm-dXkW3zK0-6XpO7BzI8hfRcByG1k7YiVzXlddTvs7QhjtgCWNcrzMBuPhoof
534-5.7.14 GjME2TgYzXJVHz5MV98nRnr_kq-kP7RmgOtX3IQHLwM5E8QGBC9-2THVQr_Ch_U0-1nZsc
534-5.7.14 yoPuNEw> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 wr6sm26888533wjc.24 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at SendEmail.sendFromGMail(SendEmail.java:50)
    at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:18)
sent
```

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail {

    private static String USER_NAME = "me";
    private static String PASSWORD = "xyz";
    private static String RECIPIENT = "abc@seecs.edu.pk";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String from = USER_NAME;
        String pass = PASSWORD;
        String[] to = { RECIPIENT };
        String subject = "Java send mail example";
        String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

        sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
        System.out.println("sent");
    }

    private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 132):

I had the same problem! Google prevents access for less secure apps.

This is how I solved it:

- Log in from your browser to that email account.
- Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- You will see **Turn off** or **Turn on**. Click on **Turn on**, then try your code again. It should work now.

Comment: It's now a checkbox and you should click "TURN ON". Please update your answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer multiple times, Thank you so much.

Comment: It works. but it is not the most elegant way of doing it. Because it leaves your mail account vulnerable as you are compromising on security

Comment: I you use the new gmail api, you don't have to enable less secure apps: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Comment: For all those this didn't work, wait for some 5 mins. For me it took some time.

Comment: Thank you, Your solution is perfect.!

Comment: I already have the less secure app TURNED ON but still I am getting this exception when I try to send email from Google VM Instance. However it works find in my local environment. Please guide.

Answer (score 104):

1. Make sure Less secure apps is **TURNED ON**
   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
   [image]
2. Allow each app to send email 
   Go to https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
   and click on Continue.
   [image]
   [image]
3. This time: you can use your app to send email and all operations are allowed.

More links:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/9KCgzXY4G_c

Comment: Does the trick for AWS EC2. I suspect Google devs will add more flags like that in the future to curb spammers. Typical "bug fixing" by some overworked developer.

Answer (score 6):

1. allow less secure apps from your google account settings
   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
2. open your gmail> goto settings > IMAP/POP settings > enable IMAP
3. goto this url and turn this on (completing all these steps will surely work)
   https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

official guide for help

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en-GB&visit_id=637246238859828954-474780158&rd=2

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing  same problem.

Google does't give you direct open port access.
If you are using your your google account for mail sending please Turn on the setting by clicking on this link.
google go here : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
Best of luck hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Its not just about enabling the "less secure apps" from google admin page.

The above fix did not solve the issue for me. I contacted google and they asked me to add couple of TXT records to my DNS list. You will need a DKIM key that you will need to generate from the G Suite admin settings for gmail.