# an exception is thrown while sending email in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and I want to send an email in Java. For that I am using this code to send the email, but this code is throwing an exception. I have verified my username and password and they are absolutely fine, so please, tell if there is any other way to send email in Java?

This is stack trace of exception:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsNX
534-5.7.14 No6jJbDc4l7fZ_WLdBD0sNHIIp_nLvplRMm0bYFBnZBF_XOyVvNSdd1FenDZJPwBTFQyRH
534-5.7.14 lriPK3myMm-dXkW3zK0-6XpO7BzI8hfRcByG1k7YiVzXlddTvs7QhjtgCWNcrzMBuPhoof
534-5.7.14 GjME2TgYzXJVHz5MV98nRnr_kq-kP7RmgOtX3IQHLwM5E8QGBC9-2THVQr_Ch_U0-1nZsc
534-5.7.14 yoPuNEw> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 wr6sm26888533wjc.24 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at SendEmail.sendFromGMail(SendEmail.java:50)
    at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:18)
sent
```

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail {

    private static String USER_NAME = "me";
    private static String PASSWORD = "xyz";
    private static String RECIPIENT = "abc@seecs.edu.pk";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String from = USER_NAME;
        String pass = PASSWORD;
        String[] to = { RECIPIENT };
        String subject = "Java send mail example";
        String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

        sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
        System.out.println("sent");
    }

    private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you read the error message at all? Go to that link and sign in.

Comment: are you enabled 2-step verification on your gmail..????

Comment: check these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778240/solve-error-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception

Comment: The 2-step verification is Disabled. @Abhishek Mishra

Comment: Checkout biniam_Ethiopia's answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341198/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-is-thrown-while-sending-email-in-java/33801654#33801654

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling SSL by adding these properties:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

And also try athenticating the `Session` like this:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
});
```

If you have enabled two-step verification you will need to create an application password and authenticate using that.

Comment: I have done what you said but now I am getting this Exception: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. cy9sm19048906wib.15 - gsmtp

Comment: @MahiraKhan Try adding this property: `props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");`

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** Google was blocking access from unknown location (app in production)

**Solution:** Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue (this will grant access for 10 minutes for registering new apps). After this my app in production started sending emails ;)