# Jenkins: Seting up mail notifications

Tags: email, jenkins

I have deployed Jenkins in OpenShift and I want to receive mail notification when my project fails. I have this config:

[image]

And when I send test mail I get this error:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14
>    Please log in via your web
>   browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14  Learn more at 534
>   5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 32sm10514455qkp.11 - gsmtp
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:522)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor592.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameB

I write the right password, so it is not the error.

Comment: Do you have two factor authentication enabled for your gmail account?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26741058/2063026) should work, if you don't have two factor authentication enabled. Else you will need to setup an application specific password

Comment: I have allowed less secure apps and it works! Thanks.