# Sending an email through R

Tags: r, email

I am using `mailR` package to send an email through `R` I am using following code

```
send.mail(from = "xyz@gmail.com",
      to = c("abc@hotmail.com"),
      #replyTo = c("Reply to someone else <someone.else@gmail.com>")
      subject = "Hi",
      body = "Hi",
      smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "xyz", passwd = "", ssl = TRUE),
      authenticate = TRUE,
      send = TRUE)
```

When I run this code I get following error.

> Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following
>   server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
>       org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465     at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)    at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
>       Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and
>       534-5.7.14 then try again.
>       534-5.7.14  Learn more at
>       534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 191sm1808499pfx.68 - gsmtp
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)    ... 6
>   more

Is it because of some security reasons gmail is blocking the access? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: did less secure apps setting on? https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: @MahmutAliÖZKURAN  Yes I did. Still does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341198/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-is-thrown-while-sending-email-in-java the solution from biniam_Ethiopia. Capthca might be the problem as you are contacting with authorization.