# Sending email in R getting Java error

Tags: r

```
`send.mail(from = "test1234@gmail.com",
 to = "recieve1234@gmailcom",
 subject = "test_email",
 body ="hi",
 smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "",passwd = "", ssl = TRUE)
 authenticate = FALSE,
 send = TRUE)`
```

Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093335/sending-an-email-through-r) possible solution is to turn on lesssecureapps got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741058/6444625)

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, you'll need to specify a username and password when connecting to GMail's SMTP server:

```
smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,
    user.name = "abhishek.gupta@gmail.com", passwd = "your_password", ssl = TRUE)
```

Also, you might have to set the `authenticate` parameter to `send.mail` to `TRUE`.