# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException sending email in Java through GMail

Tags: java, email, tomcat

I am trying to send an email in Java using Gmail as SMTP server. But I got the exception in the Title. I found this discussion on StackOverflow:
[javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException is thrown while sending email in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341198/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-is-thrown-while-sending-email-in-java)

But it didn't solve the issue, I have Gmail option enabled for less security app.

Here my Code:

```
public void send(EmailMessage msg) throws MailException {
    try {
        Session session = (Session) ServiceLocator.getInstance().getService(MAIL_JNDI_NAME);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sasadangelo@gmail.com", "Bazaar Support"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(msg.getTo(), false));     
        message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(msg.getBody(), "text/html")));
        message.setHeader("X-Mailer", "NeuroSpeech Mailer");
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        message.setSubject(msg.getSubject());
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch(NamingException exception) {
        throw new MailException(IErrorCodes.ERR_JNDI_ACCESS);
    } catch(MessagingException message) {
        throw new MailException(IErrorCodes.ERR_UNABLE_SEND_EMAIL);
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException message) {
        throw new MailException(IErrorCodes.ERR_UNABLE_SEND_EMAIL);
    }
}
```

and here my context.xml for JNDI resource:

```
<Resource name="mail/Session" auth="Container"
    type="javax.mail.Session"
    username="sasadangelo@gmail.com"
    password="********"
    mail.debug="true"
    mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
    mail.smtp.host= "smtp.gmail.com"
    mail.smtp.auth= "true"
    mail.smtp.port= "587"
    mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
    description="Global E-Mail Resource"
/>
```

User/Pwd are correct. I tried to use 465 and 587 as port. What's wrong with my code?