# Java spring boot - JavaMailSender errors

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot

I am fairly new to Java spring - I am getting the following errors when trying to send a test email.

**Error in sending email:**

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
>         nested exception is:
>         javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
>         nested exception is:
>         javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; message exceptions (1) are:
>       Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
>         nested exception is:
>         javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"

**SimepleEmailController.java**

```
package controller;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class SimpleEmailController {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    @RequestMapping("/simpleemail")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        try {
            sendEmail();
            return "Email Sent!";
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            return "Error in sending email: "+ex;
        }
    }

    private void sendEmail() throws Exception{
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setTo("set-your-recipient-email-here@gmail.com");
        helper.setText("How are you?");
        helper.setSubject("Hi");

        sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

The `application.properties` settings are as follows - testing on a test account

```
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=zzzzzzzzzzz
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true

support.mail.address=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Comment: I tried a different port - 465 -- are these configurations correct etc.. --

Comment: Please hide your personal data from code(e.g. email login pass, host, port), because it is not secure

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your `application.properties`:
`spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true`

Since your are using port `587` which is for sending message with TLS. You should use above configuration if you are using port `465` which is a SMTP SSL port.

Comment: Error in sending email: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 17sm825599ljp.80 - gsmtp  -- with port 465

Comment: Error in sending email: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;

Comment: - no still fail -- Error in sending email: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 100sm393966lfs.45 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your @ as setTo() param for a first quick test.
Then, you can let default configuration, you don't need much of it.

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=romanineers@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=****** #hope it wasn't your real password :)
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
```

Comment: so take out a bulk of properties?

Comment: protocol will be auto detected, ports have conventional default values, so yes, works fine for me..

Comment: failed --- Error in sending email: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b75sm830640lff.61 - gsmtp
; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b75sm830640lff.61 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you are getting, just set `spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true`
property value to false and try.

Comment: I think I tried - that - but will take another look

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed --- [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException is thrown while sending email in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341198/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-is-thrown-while-sending-email-in-java)   -- have to configure the gmail to allow less secure apps --

```
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=xx@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=yyyyy
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false

support.mail.address=xx@gmail.com
```