# Cannot sending email with Java

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, javax

First time I am trying to working with SMTP in java. But perhaps it can't even login to send test mail.

```
public void sendMail() throws AddressException {
    final String username = "myusername@gmail.com";
    final String password = "*******";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Subject");
        message.setText("Just Test Mail");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("SENT!");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

I don't know what is the problem with this code. It compiles fine but when i try to send the mail it just gives me following debug message:

```
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuR
    534-5.7.14 EY2k-9Ce8uWcOC3c1LSLdlFWcaIpFFpopYCeQy2niL0hD-knkk0Q58ObpnzTiGohEIx7Qz
    534-5.7.14 jXIdMVyr2CxEqnckmBMlA-IBxZnmSObE6uby8wATa6inRuZyaLWWE-gIsk5HiExKJzkNke
    534-5.7.14 LIoQEXxNYLfDrJQhYtNFJzHy1bl5ke5UqDUbReJyrEjLritFV1n5OalHDWD0Z32v75FzXS
    534-5.7.14 ttXQra4ExolIcZR7TSeU2_xGuS0g0> Please log in via your web browser and
    534-5.7.14 then try again.
    534-5.7.14  Learn more at
    534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 e6sm10484931pad.0 - gsmtp

            at money.SendMailController.sendMail(SendMailController.java:48)
            at money.MainController.sendMail(MainController.java:477)
            ... 53 more
    Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuR
    534-5.7.14 EY2k-9Ce8uWcOC3c1LSLdlFWcaIpFFpopYCeQy2niL0hD-knkk0Q58ObpnzTiGohEIx7Qz
    534-5.7.14 jXIdMVyr2CxEqnckmBMlA-IBxZnmSObE6uby8wATa6inRuZyaLWWE-gIsk5HiExKJzkNke
    534-5.7.14 LIoQEXxNYLfDrJQhYtNFJzHy1bl5ke5UqDUbReJyrEjLritFV1n5OalHDWD0Z32v75FzXS
    534-5.7.14 ttXQra4ExolIcZR7TSeU2_xGuS0g0> Please log in via your web browser and
    534-5.7.14 then try again.
    534-5.7.14  Learn more at
    534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 e6sm10484931pad.0 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:932)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:748)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at money.SendMailController.sendMail(SendMailController.java:43)
... 54 more
```

How actually i send mail through java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778240/solve-error-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception)

Comment: Did you set the property `props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");` ? Set the property and let me know the status.

Comment: And another question, did you login to your account ? try it first from web browser and test if you can login.

Comment: Yes. props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps"); was added . Tried from the browser and can login. But using java it is same errors

Comment: The problem was https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Can you send mail now from program?

Comment: Yes. But with less secure apps on. Is it possible send without touching the  less secure app configuration?

Comment: Of course you can. i think you may need ssl certificate to do that. add the properties `mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");` and set the system property `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                             "path to your jks file");
          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "your truststore password");`

Comment: What is JKS file?

Comment: java keystore file.To know, how to generate jks file, Google can be a good friend here.