# Spring - Prevent JavaMailSender from authenticating every time an email is sent

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

I am using JavaMailSender and Spring to send emails.

I instantiate the JavaMailSender load it as a property of the mailer bean and autowire the mailer bean to my controller.

I load it with the following properties:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="email@email.com" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


 <bean id="mailer" class="mz.co.crunchtech.vtchill.utils.Mailer">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>
```

I pass the *mailer* object around on my worker threads so every once in a while i get the following error:

> Exception in thread "taskExecutor-50"
>   org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later.
>   n8sm185296pgd.31 - gsmtp

I went to my logs and found various LOGIN succeeded entries as well:

[root@thikiti ~]# cat /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.73/logs/catalina.out | grep -i 'LOGIN succ' | wc -l
182

Is there a way to avoid re-authenticating each time an email is sent?

Comment: suppose you refer this [post[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778240/solve-error-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception) which discuss in more detail about this issue

Comment: Hi Rajeev this is slightly different ... i am using *Spring* JavaMailClient