# I'm trying to send mail in android but it gives me error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email with using `javax.mail` but the line of `transport.connect()` is cause to `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`.

```
public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
}
```

Comment: The server you're specifying in emailHost is rejecting the attempt to connect to it.  Probably a bad username/password, but it could be something more complex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778240/solve-error-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778240/solve-error-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception)

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Did you enable less secure apps, as described in the link above?  If so, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).