# Unable to send email using servlet and JavaMail

Tags: java, email, security, jakarta-mail

I am working on sending emails using `JavaMail`,but getting error as `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g188sm3298732pfc.24 - gsmtp`

- What i am doing is, i have a class as `EmailUtility`.
- The above class has one static method, `sendEmail()` – which takes SMTP server settings and message details as its arguments.
- I am putting SMTP server settings in my web.xml file 
  but don't know what is going wrong

My `EmailUtility` class

```
public class EmailUtility {
public static void sendEmail(String host, String port, final String userName, final String password,
        String toAddress, String subject, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    // setting SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    });
    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(message);

    // sending the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);

}
```

}

here is my web.xml file

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>host</param-name>
    <param-value>smtp.gmail.com</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>port</param-name>
    <param-value>587</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>user</param-name>
    <param-value>test.123@gmail.com</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>pass</param-name>
    <param-value>12345698</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And here is my servlet class

```
public void init() {
    // reading SMTP server setting from web.xml file
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    host = context.getInitParameter("host");
    port = context.getInitParameter("port");
    user = context.getInitParameter("user");
    pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // reading form fields
    String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");
    System.out.println(recipient+" sub "+subject+" content "+content);

    String resultMessage = "";

    try {
        EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, recipient, subject,
                content);
        resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
```

I am doing the right thing but don't know what is the issue

**If I enable Less Secure  App setting in gmail then its working fine**, i don't think it is the right approach to solve the issue as not every user is going to do that

So guys help me out, i don't know what bizarre i am making, thankyou

**Edit** is there any other  resource by which i can send mails on cross platforms like from gmail to yahoo like that, i am open to use any other resource which can do the task i am trying to

Comment: If you know you are going to use GMail, what about using Google's Java API for GMail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java ?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek it will depend on who is using the app the can change accordingly

Comment: @JozefChocholacek any solution on the basis of what i am doing already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2965433/11148620

Comment: @YaroslavNudnenko i am doing the same thing sir, but still stuck

Comment: @dheerajkumar can in gmail two-factor authorization?

Comment: @YaroslavNudnenko sorry didn't get you? when i am https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps enabaling it then mails are sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different servers have different security requirements.  If you want to handle all of them, you're going to need some special cases in your application.

Sometimes you'll need the user to create an app-specific password for the email server.

Sometimes you'll need to support [OAuth](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2) if the server supports it.